# RabbitMQ - How to group datasets

Tags: php, ubuntu, rabbitmq

I have this setup where a bunch of customers needs to have some data crunched.

I am using RabbitMQ to store the data and a consumer to dispatch it for the workers.

The setup works, but if one customer has a large amount of data, it will delay the other customers.

So how can run the tasks in parallel grouped by the customer ?

Bonus info:

- Every customer has a unique key stored in the dataset.
- I am using rabbitmq-cli-consumer.
- The workers are written in php.

EDIT:

This is how the setup works.

The customers can have data in all 3 queues.

Each queue handles a different data type.

I am not a master at diagrams, but here is a try at it.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: In what sense does RabbitMQ 'store' data?  The purpose of a messaging system is for the (transient) transmission of data/messages from one system to another.  Presumably something must be sending the data to RabbitMQ, and workers are processing it.  To get an answer - it might help to clarify your existing architecture, and existing exchange/queue topography you have set up.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I will clarify in the original post.